# When did individual graves and modern cemetary and tombstones become common place?

Tags: death, ceremony

There is already a question on when the [tombstone was first recorded](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/first-recorded-use-of-a-traditional-tombstone), but my question is when did the modern Western concepts of [cemeteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cemetery) with organized plots and tombstones and other markers with their names and dates become common place... not just for the noble, rich, and otherwise notable individuals but for the 'common man' with a modest life?

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree that cemeteries with organized plots and tombstones has ever been a 'common man' benefit. It is an end result of an upper-middle class (and higher) life. Anything less and you end up in an unmarked grave, or worse.